# CSS: shades darker and lighter

Tags: css

I'm trying to use some sort of "darker than" or "lighter than" tag in my CSS page definitions...
Is there any such a thing, or do people have a suggestion of a way that one could do this?

Thanks,
jml

Comment: this is a nice potential jquery (or similar) add in imo!

Comment: interesting... yeah; i think i am going to get into jquery- it seems real slick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Technically, no...

No,  you'll have to explicitly declare a color. You could jump into photoshop and copy the hex of your favorite color from the color-palette.

#### But if you're really smooth, you can...

One other option to simulate shades is to use transparent png files, and setting them as the background image over the top of a background color.

```
.red       { background-color:red; }
.darkerRed { background:red url("fiftyPercentOpaqueBlack.png"); }
```

#### And now for an example...

For example, the .png below is actually solid black, with an opacity of 50% which creates a shade of grey when viewed on top of white, or `#ffffff`.

[image]

Comment: hmm; that's interesting.
i'll check into it if i get really desperate.  :)
for now, i think that the rgb() call will work... i also don't mind looking up colors individually.

i had an idea about it where i could just build the color scheme in a program like illustrator or whatnot and then somehow copy the schem over...

Comment: this certainly seems like a viable option if you are embarking on a larger project.  for my specific needs it seems like overkill as i'm just trying to change text colors...